# Codeigniter 3.0 Pagination "Make prev_link & next_link visiable all time"

Tags: codeigniter

I have got my codeigniter 3.0 **pagination library working with bootstrap pagination**

But when I am at the 1st page as shown on image the `<<` does not show and if I am on the 2nd page `>>` does not show either.

**Question** What ever page I am on I would like at both ends of the pagination to make the << >> visible. Is that possible and what would be the best solution?

[image]

[image]

```
<?php

class Lists extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $this->load->model('layouts/model_layouts');

        $data['layouts'] = array();

        $config["base_url"] = base_url('layout/lists');
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->model_layouts->count_total();
        $config["per_page"] = 5;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';            
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        $results = $this->model_layouts->get_layouts($config["per_page"], $page); 

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['layouts'][] = array(
                'layout_id' => $result['layout_id'],
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'status' => ($result['status'] ? '<div class="label label-info">Enabled</div>' : '<div class="label label-danger">Disabled</div>'),
                'edit' => site_url('layout/edit/' . $result['layout_id']),
                'delete' => site_url('layout/delete/' . $result['layout_id']),
            );
        }

        $data['admin_page'] = 'template/layouts/layout_list';

        $this->load->view('template/common/template_design', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-do-pagination-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @Ricky I have got the pagination working. I just would like to be able to keep the `$config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';` and `$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';` visible at all times.

Comment: Pagination link is already visible in codeigniter library.

Comment: For that you need to change the CI pagination library code. There is no option to show link all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Comment: Updated now. Check once